# How I can center the caption figure in a figure* enviroment?

Tags: floats

I use `\begin{figure*}` to insert a figure in a double column in LaTeX, but the caption is aligned on the left. How I can center the caption?

Comment: it doesnt work :/

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) While I strongly suspect that some user here might be able to read minds `:-)`, unfortunately most of us can't, and we actually need to look at some code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: Position of caption is depends on caption's settings  if you use `caption` package or on definitions in the used document class. For helping you we need to see MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem.

Comment: @cfr - \caption fills the entire \textwidth, so \centering has no effect.  Any formatting is built in.

Comment: The positioning of `\caption` is often determined by the document class or a package.  So if we don't know what those are, we can't do anything but guess, which isn't very productive.

Comment: This is the document file that i dowload: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates.zip, im using the double column also here is a litle descrption: https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=Elsarticle_-_CAS#Figures                 
Sorry if i dont describre with details the problem...